# Convert a *.mif format file to a *.csv point file without loosing attributes

Tags: qgis, convert

I tried to convert from .mif to .csv in two steps.

- Step1- Save as .shp from Layer
- Step2- Convert Polygon/line vertices to Points.

Now, when I tried to do "Point Statistics for Polygons", then an attribute is missing in the Points, which I need.

Is there a way to convert exactly all the attributes of the .mif apple to apple to point so that I can use the function "Point Statistics for Polygons"?

Comment: what do you mean by `attributes of the .mif apple to apple to point`

Comment: I mean all the attributes of .mif is not getting coverted to point. Some fields are missing.

Comment: About `apple to apple` https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13548/what-does-apples-to-apples-phrase-mean

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is (using QGIS 2.18.17). I don't think you need to save your .mif file as as shapefile in the first step. I tried this directly with a .mif file with attributes like

[image]

There are (at least) two tools from the processing toolbox taken into account for what you try to achieve, whichs GUIs look (nearly) exactly the same, but differ in the resulting points / attributes:

**1) SAGA | Vector polygon tools | Convert polygon/line vertices to points**

[image]

... this tool does not keep the attribute structure:

[image]

**2) QGIS | Vector geometry tools | Extract nodes**

[image]

... this tool DOES keep the attribute structure:

[image]